# Replacing line segments with points in a density plot

Tags: r, plot, kernel-density, probability-density, density-plot

I was wondering how I could replace the 7 line `segments` that are currently showing with `points`? That is, instead of the 7 black line `segments` I need 7 lines of `points` going from the bottom of each of the line `segments` up to the curve line? (***Instead of 7 line segments, I then will have 7 vertical lines of points***)

**Please see my R code below the picture.**

[image]

```
A = rnorm(1e3)

B = density(A)

x = B$x  ;  y = (B$y)*(B$n)

plot(x, y, type = "l")

x.DEN = seq(-3, 3)
y.DEN = approx(x, y, xout = x.DEN )$y

segments(x.DEN, par("usr")[3], x.DEN, y.DEN) ## HERE I need points
```

Comment: What is the point of this? Do you just want to show a dotted line? Because then you can just add an `lty = 3` in your `segment` call

Comment: @MikeH., no i need `points` (pch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea, if you NEED to have points would be to use `mapply` to get the position of the points that you want and then `lapply` to add them all to the graph. Something like this:

```
mypoints <- mapply(function(x, y, z) data.frame(y = seq(x, y, length.out=floor((y-x)/5)),
                                                x = z),
                     x = rep(par("usr")[3], length(y.DEN)),
                     y = y.DEN,
                     z = x.DEN ,SIMPLIFY = F)

lapply(mypoints, function(z) points(x = z$x, y = z$y))
```

[image]

From there you can change the size/point type to whatever you want. You can also add more or less points by dividing by a lower/higher number in the `length.out=...`. I chose 5 because it seemed to look good.